# Why aren't namespaces included in controller names with requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an authorization method that is intercepting requests on ApplicationController and sending to a module I built that extends User.

It looks like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def authorized?(action="#{action_name}", controller="#{controller_name.singularize}")
    current_user.authorize(current_user.role, controller, action)
  end

  def authorize
    redirect_to unauthorized_path unless authorized?
  end
end
```

This works great, but today I wanted to use a controller under a namespace:

```
class Trainings::ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize
  ...
end
```

When I look at the request though, the controller name is just `resources`. I would have expected it to reference Training. It's the first controller so it's not a problem now, but as soon as I have something like a `Clients::ResourcesController` it's going to break my auth module if they don't have the same permissions.

Why doesn't the controller name include the namespace in the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**:

It doesn't include the name space because it's not supposed to.

**Longer answer**:

There is an important incorrect assumption in the question: `controller_name` is not passed as part of the request, it is a helper method defined in [ActionController](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f03889136adc01c202b17a14562fbd9a72db9997/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L129).

The namespace is not included because this method explicitly removes namespaces by [calling `demodulize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-demodulize) on the name that is passed in.

Knowing this is the expected behavior, it would be better to re-write the `authorized?` method on ApplicationController to use something like `class` as praga suggests.

Answer (score 0):

self.class.to_s works!. It gets you with name space. See my log below

```
def authorized?(action="#{action_name}", controller="#{controller_name.singularize}")
        puts "action:#{action_name}--controller:#{self.class.to_s}"
        current_user.authorize(current_user.role, controller, action)
      end

  def authorize
    redirect_to unauthorized_path unless authorized?
  end

    Started GET "/clients/resources" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 at 2018-04-14 18:29:34 +0530
    Processing by Clients::ResourcesController#index as HTML
    action:index--controller:Clients::ResourcesController

Started GET "/trainings/resources" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 at 2018-04-14 18:33:52 +0530
Processing by Trainings::ResourcesController#index as HTML
action:index--controller:Trainings::ResourcesController
```

Comment: Thanks! I was really hoping to know why it was behaving this way, but I did some source diving and found out (see answer). This is a good suggestion to fix it now that I know what's going on.